# HTML5 Canvas + js game | Reset game on death changes the game speeds up?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a game using HTML5's canvas and javascript.  I believe that I have been doing everything *"okay"* up until the point where I need to reset the game on death.  I'm not really sure what is causing the unexpected behavior but i have thoughts.

Pretty much, the game operates at 'x' speed and then when it resets everything is moving much faster.  I have not changed any of the variables for any speed of anything and when debugging and inspecting my code the speeds are the same on the newly created objects as the first time the game is started but they are moving much faster.  If you die again it resets again and operates even faster.  Die, rinse, repeat and it keeps speeding up until the page would probably hit "not responding" state.

I don't know *for sure* what I'm doing wrong that is causing the speed difference or at least the illusion of the speed difference.  I have an idea that it has something to do with my game loop running multiple times into forever every time it's reset but I don't understand how/why it would do that.  any feedback is appreciated.

Also, you can visit my testing page to see all of the code if you need more than I posted below:  [game test playground](http://sammynorth.com/gametestpage.html)

```
var windowx,
windowy,
canvas,
player,
quadTree,
ctx;

var drawObjects;
var keyState;

var mainloop;
var animFrame;
var ONE_FRAME_TIME;

var reset = function () {

//get canvas and set height and width
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('width', windowx / 2);
canvas.setAttribute('height', windowy / 2);
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
drawObjects = [];
keyState = {};
quadTree = new Quadtree(quadTreeBounds);


//make the friendly square
player = new Rectangle(20, 20, 40, 40, 0, 0, XPhysicsBehaviorNormal, YPhysicsBehaviorNormal, XBoundaryBehaviorInCanvas, YBoundaryBehaviorInCanvas, playerObjectType, '#580000', null);
drawObjects.push(player);
drawObjects.push(new Rectangle(40, 100, canvas.width + (distanceOutsideCanvasBeforeDie / 2), canvas.clientHeight - 100, defaultEnemyRectangleVelocity, 0, null, YPhysicsBehaviorNormal, null, YBoundaryBehaviorInCanvas, enemyObjectType, null, OutOfCanvasDieBehavior));


backgroundMusicAudio.play();

//define main loop
mainloop = function () {
    buildQuadTree();
    updateGame();
    drawGame();
};

//define the windowanimationframeobject
animFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    null;

if (animFrame !== null) {
    var recursiveAnim = function () {
        mainloop();
        animFrame(recursiveAnim, canvas);
    };

    // start the mainloop
    animFrame(recursiveAnim, canvas);
} else {
    // fallback to setInterval if the browser doesn't support requestAnimationFrame
    ONE_FRAME_TIME = 1000.0 / 60.0;
    setInterval(mainloop, ONE_FRAME_TIME);
}
}

$(function () {
//get window width and height;
windowx = window.innerWidth;
windowy = window.innerHeight;

reset();

$(document).on('change', '#sound-enabled-toggle', function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('#sound-enabled-toggle').blur();
    if (isChecked) {
        backgroundMusicAudio.play();
        playerJumpAudio = playerJumpMusicAudioSetup();
        playerBlinkAudio = playerBlinkMusicAudioSetup();
    } else {
        backgroundMusicAudio.pause();
        playerJumpAudio = new Audio('');
        playerBlinkAudio = new Audio('');
    }
});
});

//left the function here in case I need to do anything else but for now it's  just clearing.
function buildQuadTree() {
    quadTree.clear();
}

function updateGame() {

//determine if there are any keys pushed at the current point
keyPressActions();

//loop for calculating and updating all objects positions/values.
for (var i = 0; i < drawObjects.length; i++) {
    var object = drawObjects[i];
    quadTree.insert(new SimpleRectangle(object.x, object.y, object.width || (object.radius * 2), object.height || (object.radius * 2), object.name));
    object.update();

    //roundFloatingPoints Numbers to 2 decimal places
    roundObjectVelocitiesAndPoints(object);
}
PlayerDeathTrigger(player);
}

function drawGame() {
//clear the canvas
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.font = "20px Verdana";
ctx.fillText("100,000", (canvas.width * .8), (canvas.clientHeight * .1));
ctx.font = "15px Verdana";
ctx.fillText("Temp Score", (canvas.width * .8), (canvas.clientHeight * .05));

//draw all objects in drawObjects
for (var i = 0; i < drawObjects.length; i++) {
    var object = drawObjects[i];
    object.draw();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall I would recommend re-factoring this code so your reset function doesn't re-create so many objects. Basically the reset function is just re-creating a bulk of the game logic.

The specific issue you identified appears to be coming from the fact that you call setInterval on each reset without clearing the previous interval. See the code below with the minimal changes to prevent this issue.

```
var windowx,
    windowy,
    canvas,
    player,
    quadTree,
    ctx,
    gameLoop;

var drawObjects;
var keyState;

var mainloop;
var animFrame;
var ONE_FRAME_TIME;

var reset = function() {

    // Remove our old game loop
    clearInterval(gameLoop);

    //get canvas and set height and width
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', windowx / 2);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', windowy / 2);
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    drawObjects = [];
    keyState = {};
    quadTree = new Quadtree(quadTreeBounds);


    //make the friendly square
    player = new Rectangle(20, 20, 40, 40, 0, 0, XPhysicsBehaviorNormal, YPhysicsBehaviorNormal, XBoundaryBehaviorInCanvas, YBoundaryBehaviorInCanvas, playerObjectType, '#580000', null);
    drawObjects.push(player);
    drawObjects.push(new Rectangle(40, 100, canvas.width + (distanceOutsideCanvasBeforeDie / 2), canvas.clientHeight - 100, defaultEnemyRectangleVelocity, 0, null, YPhysicsBehaviorNormal, null, YBoundaryBehaviorInCanvas, enemyObjectType, null, OutOfCanvasDieBehavior));


    backgroundMusicAudio.play();

    //define main loop
    mainloop = function() {
        buildQuadTree();
        updateGame();
        drawGame();
    };

    //define the windowanimationframeobject
    animFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        null;

    if (animFrame !== null) {
        var recursiveAnim = function() {
            mainloop();
            animFrame(recursiveAnim, canvas);
        };

        // start the mainloop
        animFrame(recursiveAnim, canvas);
    } else {
        // fallback to setInterval if the browser doesn't support requestAnimationFrame
        ONE_FRAME_TIME = 1000.0 / 60.0;
        gameLoop = setInterval(mainloop, ONE_FRAME_TIME);
    }
}

$(function() {
    //get window width and height;
    windowx = window.innerWidth;
    windowy = window.innerHeight;

    reset();

    $(document).on('change', '#sound-enabled-toggle', function() {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        $('#sound-enabled-toggle').blur();
        if (isChecked) {
            backgroundMusicAudio.play();
            playerJumpAudio = playerJumpMusicAudioSetup();
            playerBlinkAudio = playerBlinkMusicAudioSetup();
        } else {
            backgroundMusicAudio.pause();
            playerJumpAudio = new Audio('');
            playerBlinkAudio = new Audio('');
        }
    });
});

//left the function here in case I need to do anything else but for now it's  just clearing.
function buildQuadTree() {
    quadTree.clear();
}

function updateGame() {

    //determine if there are any keys pushed at the current point
    keyPressActions();

    //loop for calculating and updating all objects positions/values.
    for (var i = 0; i < drawObjects.length; i++) {
        var object = drawObjects[i];
        quadTree.insert(new SimpleRectangle(object.x, object.y, object.width || (object.radius * 2), object.height || (object.radius * 2), object.name));
        object.update();

        //roundFloatingPoints Numbers to 2 decimal places
        roundObjectVelocitiesAndPoints(object);
    }
    PlayerDeathTrigger(player);
}

function drawGame() {
    //clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.font = "20px Verdana";
    ctx.fillText("100,000", (canvas.width * .8), (canvas.clientHeight * .1));
    ctx.font = "15px Verdana";
    ctx.fillText("Temp Score", (canvas.width * .8), (canvas.clientHeight * .05));

    //draw all objects in drawObjects
    for (var i = 0; i < drawObjects.length; i++) {
        var object = drawObjects[i];
        object.draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that reset interval and cancelanimationframe but they didn't work so i took your refactor advice.  I thought "i guess the loop should never stop but my game objects should just clear and reset so the only thing in my reset function now is the clearing of the drawobjects and keys.  then creating a player and a block.  It works great.  Thanks.

Comment: Awesome. I am glad you got it working. I would suggest making an edit to your post and sharing the working code for anyone else who wants to reference this question in the future. Cheers!